# Solving constraint satisfaction problems in Sympy

Tags: sympy, smt, constraint-programming

I'm attempting to solve some simple [Boolean satisfiability problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) in Sympy. Here, I tried to solve a constraint that contains the `Or` logic operator:

```
from sympy import *
a,b = symbols("a b")

print(solve(Or(Eq(3, b*2), Eq(3, b*3))))
# In other words: (3 equals b*2) or (3 equals b*3)
# [1,3/2] was the answer that I expected
```

Surprisingly, this leads to an error instead:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Or' and 'int'
```

I can work around this problem using `Piecewise`, but this is much more verbose:

```
from sympy import *
a,b = symbols("a b")
print(solve(Piecewise((Eq(3, b*2),Eq(3, b*2)), (Eq(3, b*3),Eq(3, b*3)))))
#prints [1,3/2], as expected
```

Unfortunately, this work-around fails when I try to solve for two variables instead of one:

```
from sympy import *
a,b = symbols("a b")

print(solve([Eq(a,3+b),Piecewise((Eq(b,3),Eq(b,3)), (Eq(b,4),Eq(b,4)))]))
#AttributeError: 'BooleanTrue' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Is there a more reliable way to solve constraints like this one in Sympy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on zaq's answer, SymPy doesn't recognize logical operators in `solve`, but you can use the fact that

```
a*b = 0
```

is equivalent to

```
a = 0 OR b = 0
```

That is, multiply the two equations

```
solve((3 - 2*b)*(3 - 3*b), b)
```

As an additional note, if you wanted to use AND instead of OR, you can solve for a system. That is,

```
solve([eq1, eq2])
```

is equivalent to solving

```
eq1 = 0 AND eq2 = 0
```

Comment: This method sometimes works when the formula is written in [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), but it doesn't always give all possible solutions. For example: in `(y-x = 1) AND ((x = 1) OR (1/(1-x) = 1/2))`, one of the equations has a solution while the other equation is undefined, so it won't give all solutions in this case.

Comment: @AndersonGreen you can use `solve(check=False)` to disable the checks that a solution makes a denominator zero. `solve((1 - x)*(1/(1 - x) - S(1)/2), x, check=False)` gives `[-1, 1]`.

Comment: Sympy also has a [logic module](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html); can it [convert Boolean expressions to polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244230/converting-boolean-expressions-to-polynomials) in order to solve them?

Answer (score 4):

Every equation can be expressed as something being equated to 0. For example, 3-2*b = 0 instead of 3 = 2*b. (In Sympy, you don't even have to write the `=0` part, it's assumed.) Then you can simply multiply equations to express the OR logic:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> a,b = symbols("a b")
>>> solve((3-b*2)*(3-b*3))
[1, 3/2]
>>> solve([a-3-b, (3-b*2)*(3-b*3)])
[{b: 1, a: 4}, {b: 3/2, a: 9/2}]
```